# How to include all the data in foreach loop inside a table

Tags: php, laravel, loops, view, controller

```
@foreach($lastactivity as $activity)  
{{ $activity }}
@endforeach
```

That is the for loop.

Now this is the output in the view.

```
{"id":2,"log_name":"index-log","description":"I visited index","subject_id":null,"subject_type":null,"causer_id":1,"causer_type":"App\\User","properties":[],"created_at":"2017-07-18 11:05:08","updated_at":"2017-07-18 11:05:08"}
```

How will I be able to put that in a table with all the columns and data arranged? Thank you very much.

Comment: you should just write [table html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) and replace the content of the `td`'s with your values. The rows are the content of the `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

You should use table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
               <th>Log Name</th>
               <th>Description</th>
        </tr> 
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach($lastactivity as $activity)
        <tr>
               <td>{{$activity->log_name}}</td>
               <td>{{$activity->description}}</td>
        </tr> 
   @endforeach  
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In the same way, Add other fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
Like this:


    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Log Name</th>
         .
         .
         .
        <th>Updated At</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($lastactivity as $activity)  
     <tr>
        <td>{{ $activity->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $activity->log_name }}</td>
             .
             .
             .
        <td>{{ $activity-> }}</td>
      </tr> 
    @endforeach    
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your field name

```
{{ $activity->id }}
{{ $activity->log_name }}
```

etc